# Python3, Tkinter, and User input request for time

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods, tkinter, clock

I'm really making some progress on basic concepts and verbiage in Python, but I'm getting a little lost when we start adding Tkinter into the mix. BryanOakley made a great contribution to a question about multiple windows and Tkinter that's everywhere on the web. I took his example, combined it with some other examples I've seen and have started to make a clock with an alarm that should change the clock background when the alarm time kick in. Problem is, I just can't see the trees through the forest and don't see how to:

> A) Get input request to appear from the Tkinter window
>   B) Call the user's input in the alarm class into the clock class to trigger a window background change.

I think my issue is I don't completely understand where to nest the different methods and how to take a variable storing the user data, and format it from string to time. I think I just need some guidance, but if you think i'm over my head, then please point me to the shallow end so I can keep practicing. Here was my thought, put this or something like it into the tick() method, of course I have to wonder where the input would even be entered in Tkinter. I'm spiraling. Help:

```
def wake(self):
    self.__init__(self, hour, min)
    self.hour = hour
    self.min = min
        input("what is the hour?",
        input("What is the min?", 
    hour = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I")
    min = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%M")
    if self.hour and self.min == time1():
        label.config(text = time1, bg = "green")
    else:
        label.config(text = time1, bg = "red")
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
import datetime


class digitalClockApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=100, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill= "both", expand =1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (introPage, clock, alarm):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent = container, controller = self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
            self.geometry("640x480")

        self.show_frame("introPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class introPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Welcome", bg = "black", fg = "white", font = controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = 1)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Go to Clock", command = lambda: controller.show_frame("clock"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Go to Set Alarm", command = lambda: controller.show_frame("alarm"))
        button1.pack(side = "left")
        button2.pack(side = "left")

class clock(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "", bg = "black", fg = "white", font = controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = 1)
        button = tk.Button(self, text = "Home Screen", command = lambda: controller.show_frame("introPage"))
        button.pack()

        def tick(time1 = ""):
            time2 = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S")
            if time2 != time1:
                time1 = time2
                label.config(text = time1, bg = "red")
            label.after(200, tick)

        tick()

class alarm(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "", bg = "black", fg = "white", font = controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = 1)
        def wake():
        button = tk.Button(self, text = "Home Screen", command = lambda: controller.show_frame("introPage"))
        button.pack()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = digitalClockApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, I think the concept of switching frames is a bad choice for someone learning to use tkinter. That example was never intended to be used as a starting point for beginners, especially for something as simple as an alarm clock. It adds a lot of overhead with very little benefit.

My recommendation is to start over with a single window. Add entry widgets for the hours and minutes, a label to show the clock, and a button to start the clock. That's all you need for this exercise. It would probably be a couple dozen lines of code.

Your `tick` method can probably be used more or less as-is, though I don't see the point of updating the clock five times a second if you're only showing time to whole seconds.

Only after you get that working should you start trying to work with advanced architectures like the "switching frames" code.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: So, I'm trying your suggestion, but I'm just getting hung up once I add multiple methods into a class. It seems I can define the class, get the clock to run, but the second I try to add a button for an alarm, I wind up with attribute errors, or errors indicating variables being called before they are defined. Is there a trick to the order of the methods within a class when using Tkinter?

Comment: @RL_NooB: there are no tricks other than standard programming practices: define things before you use them, save references to things that you need in multiple places, etc.

Comment: I'll keep at it. I think I started out with more than I can chew, but I'm learning a lot by struggling here. Thanks again.